# DateTime.TryParse doesn't accept nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

so I have this nullable variable I created:

```
private DateTime? _startDate;
```

I wanted to parse some variable to DateTime and then assign it to this variable, but the VS complains that the `TryParse` method has some invalid arguments.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["StartDate"]) == false)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(Request.Form["StartDate"], out _startDate);
        }
        else
        { _startDate = null; }
```

Is there a syntax error I have or I can't use nullable variables in here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `DateTime.TryParse()` doesn't accept `DateTime?` because `DateTime?` is really `Nullable<DateTime>` - not a compatible type.

Try this instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["StartDate"]) == false)
    {
        var dtValue = new DateTime();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Request.Form["StartDate"], out dtValue)) {
            _startDate = dtValue;
        }
        else {
            _startDate = null;
        }
    }
    else
    { _startDate = null; }
```

Comment: Note that there really isn't a need for the null or empty check - DateTime.TryParse will do this for you, which could simplify this block a bit.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, good point. The only part needed is the `true` part of the conditional after the current check for `IsNullOrEmpty(...)`.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `dtValue` either, as it's used for an `out` parameter.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know. It's an OCD thing. It just kills me to see variables declared without explicit initialization. I go to group meetings for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet In this case, does the initialization actually do anything (as it's a value type using default construction)?  Wouldn't the resulting IL be the same as `DateTime dtValue;`

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Not sure, to be honest. Personally I just don't like seeing a value in my code which will never be used.

Comment: @ReedCopsey FWIW, ReSharper complains to me that the initialization is redundant.

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, they're not compatible types. I would suggest you create a new method which wraps `DateTime.TryParse` and *returns* a `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
// Add appropriate overloads to match TryParse and TryParseExact
public static DateTime? TryParseNullableDateTime(string text)
{
    DateTime value;
    return DateTime.TryParse(text, out value) ? value : (DateTime?) null;
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
_startDate = Helpers.TryParseNullableDateTime(Request.Form["StartDate"]);
```

(No need to check for null or empty string; `TryParse` will just return false in that case anyway.)

Comment: +1 Something I'd like to see added to the `Nullable<T>` class.

Comment: @Yuck: I like both `TryParseSomeType` and `TryParseNullableSomeType`, depending on context.  However, I think providing both calls would pollute the member list, and I don't have a strong preference in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime?` and `DateTime` are different and non-compatible types in relation to `out`. So you need to use DateTime and then copy value as in Yuck's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. Exception is been handled.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["StartDate"]) == false)
        {
            DateTime strtDate;
            try
              {
                strtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["StartDate"]);
                _startDate = strtDate;
              }
            catch(Exception)
              {
               _startDate = null;
              }
         }
        else
        { 
       _startDate = null;
        }
```